# Full left outer join with less/more than or equal conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes that I want to perform a simple full outer left join with condition less than or equal.

```
d1 = {'object': ['A1', 'B2', 'C1'], 
      'start_date': ['2019-01-19', '2009-07-03', '2021-11-23'],
      'end_date': ['2019-03-15', '2009-10-28', '2024-12-22']
     }
df1 = pandas.DataFrame(data=d1)
```

The other dataframe is simply a calendar:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.date_range('1990-01-01', '2050-12-31')})
df["first_day_of_month"] = df["date"].to_numpy().astype('datetime64[M]')
```

I would like to get results that are similar with this type of sql:

```
SELECT * FROM df1 LEFT JOIN df2
ON df1.start_date <= df2.date AND df1.end_date >= df2.date
WHERE df2.first_day_of_month = 1
```

So every row in df1 repeated with all the `df2.first_day_of_month`
of the months that are between `df1.start_date` and `df2.end_date`.

How can I achieve this result?

Edit: the resulted dataframe would be like:

| Object | start_date | end_date | df2.date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 2019-01-19 | 2019-03-15 | 2019-02-01 |
| A1 | 2019-01-19 | 2019-03-15 | 2019-03-01 |
| B2 | 2009-07-03 | 2009-10-28 | 2009-08-01 |
| B2 | 2009-07-03 | 2009-10-28 | 2009-09-01 |
| B2 | 2009-07-03 | 2009-10-28 | 2009-10-01 |

Comment: What would be the expected output (maybe provide a smaller `df2` as example)?

Comment: @mozway I've added a small sample of expected output

Comment: are the ranges overlapping?

Comment: @mozway the ranges of the df1 can overlap between objects. for example the start_date and end_date of object A1 can be same with object C3. the calendar table contains unduplicated dates from 1990-01-01 to 2050-12-31

Comment: The `WHERE df2.first_day_of_month = 1` condition is not fully clear to me, anyway check the answer below and let me know if this doesn't work the way you want (provide a counter example)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`janitor`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor)'s [`conditional_join`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join):

```
# pip install janitor
import janitor

df1['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['start_date'])
df1['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['end_date'])
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])

out = df1.conditional_join(df2[df2['first_day_of_month'].dt.day.eq(1)],
                           ('start_date', 'date', '<='),
                           ('end_date', 'date', '>='),
                           how='left')
```

Output:

```
     object start_date   end_date       date first_day_of_month
0        A1 2019-01-19 2022-12-15 2019-01-19         2019-01-01
1        A1 2019-01-19 2022-12-15 2019-01-20         2019-01-01
2        A1 2019-01-19 2022-12-15 2019-01-21         2019-01-01
3        A1 2019-01-19 2022-12-15 2019-01-22         2019-01-01
4        A1 2019-01-19 2022-12-15 2019-01-23         2019-01-01
...     ...        ...        ...        ...                ...
5435     C1 2021-11-23 2024-12-22 2024-12-18         2024-12-01
5436     C1 2021-11-23 2024-12-22 2024-12-19         2024-12-01
5437     C1 2021-11-23 2024-12-22 2024-12-20         2024-12-01
5438     C1 2021-11-23 2024-12-22 2024-12-21         2024-12-01
5439     C1 2021-11-23 2024-12-22 2024-12-22         2024-12-01

[5440 rows x 5 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello there you can use the following logic :)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d1 = {
    'object': ['A1', 'B2', 'C1'],
    'start_date': ['2019-01-19', '2009-07-03', '2021-11-23'],
    'end_date': ['2022-12-15', '2017-05-28', '2024-12-22']
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.date_range('1990-01-01', '2050-12-31')})
df2_filtered = df2[df2["date"].dt.day == 1]

# Create a common key for joining
df1['key'] = 1
df2_filtered['key'] = 1

# Perform the cross join
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2_filtered, on='key', how='outer')

# Drop the key column
merged_df = merged_df.drop(columns='key')

# Apply the conditions
filtered_df = merged_df[
    (merged_df['start_date'] <= merged_df['date']) & (merged_df['end_date'] >= merged_df['date'])
]

filtered_df

# Reset the index
filtered_df = filtered_df.reset_index(drop=True)

# Print the resulting dataframe
print(filtered_df)
```

[image: Here is the result of the desired]

Comment: Note that there is no need to create an outer key, a cross join would do the same. Also, this "combine all then filter" method is not efficient as you will create all combinations of rows. If both inputs are large this might just crash.